# How to introduce CQRS to an existing project?

Tags: elasticsearch, cqrs

I want to introduce CQRS using asynchronous events and read models stored in elasticsearch.

I have two questions:

1. How can I fill elasticsearch by data to make it consistent with entire system? I have a lot of data in other microservices (user, item etc.). After deploy feature with CQRS elasticsearch will listen for different events to track system state.
2. What are strategies to make elasticsearch consistent with entire system when something went wrong (for example RabbitMQ didn't consume some events).

Answer (score 1):

Well the way you are placing up the scenarios , the two things those directly strike are :

1. Eventual Consistency
2. Following Saga patterns to take care of reverting the data

If you are having some write database other than elastic search then probably sending events through some messaging broker only can make the data consistent in elastic search engine.

In case any data revert is to be done then probably saga patterns are to be followed.